# mediaelement.js youtube preview image

Tags: iphone, html, youtube, mediaelement.js

I use Contao 3 an the youtube content element, which basically is the mediaelement.js Plugin.
As soon as I add an preview image, which is seen, before we click on the video to start playing.
On desktop computers it works fine.
On mobile phones / Tablets (Iphone, Ipad) i doesn't work. We can't press play or start the video. As soon as I remove the picture, it works.
Are there any known problems with this?
thx